# Extract sharp edges from triangle mesh and its contour and render it with openGL

Tags: c++, opengl, mesh, edge-detection

I'm trying to render an object in openGL (3.3) in a wire-frame style, but only its sharp edges (i.e. if the adjacent face normals have a certain delta angle) and its contour/silhouette/boundary. My data-structure is a triangle mesh with only the triangles and its vertices stored.
I've looked into ["Hardware Determined Edge Features" by Morgan McGuire and John F. Hughes](http://graphics.cs.williams.edu/papers/EdgesNPAR04/index.html) and
["Hardware Generated Object Silhouettes" by Michal Valient](http://www.dimension3.sk/downloads/valient_silhouettes_g2005_web.pdf)
both calculate edges/face-normals/silhouettes online which is why both of them have to implement some "workaround" to be able to use the GPU for the edge-determining.

I thought it would be best to determine once the sharp edges offline and store this information somehow for later rendering and determine the object's contour/silhouette/boundary online dependent on the viewpoint.

During my search I stumbled upon CGAL, half-edges, OpenMesh but have no experience using any of it.

My questions would be:
How to determine the sharp edges? Or go through the mesh, create an adjacency list and test all edges? (cross-product to get the face-normals and dot-product to get the angle between them)
How to store this in a good way, so to be able to render it easily later on? Create degenerate triangles for the dull edges? Does too much information get lost this way? Use a format which stores lines, and draw them?
How to then render them?

How to determine the contour/silhouette online?

This is kind of a broad question but I hope someone can guide me in a direction or maybe has even done this before with one of the mentioned libraries (CGAL, OpenMesh).

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not wrong, a sharp edge always depends on a viewpoint. You must have a "point of view" to decide wether a normal is poiting towards the front or the back.

That's what it is often done in geometry shaders instead of just once on the CPU (which can not work if you want to move the camera).

For the geometry shader technique, you need to send triangles + their adjacency. This can be computed only once using an halfedges structure (the quick and easy way), or you can have a loop like

```
for each triangle t1
    for each triangle t2
        if t2 has 2 indices common with t1 then
            add t2 to t1 adjacency list
        endif
    endfor
endfor
```

Then you build your index list (that you will send to the GPU) using this information, which might look like

```
for each triangle t1
    indexList.append(t1.a, t1.b, t1.c)
    for each triangle t2 in t1 adjacency
        idx = find the index not common with t1
        indexList.append(idx)
    endfor
endfor
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. As I understand it sharp edges stay sharp edges no matter what the "point of view" is (if backface culling is used for omitting the backwards facing parts). No? 
Would a good way to go about be to create a halfedge-structure to easily calculate adjacent face normals and then store the lines which are sharp edges in e.g. an obj-file and render via GL_LINES? 

Only for the silhouette the "point of view" is needed as explained e.g. [here](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial39/tutorial39.html). Correct?

Comment: Maybe have a look at this paper http://e-collection.library.ethz.ch/eserv/eth:4390/eth-4390-01.pdf (mesh edge detection) to find sharp edges. You will still have work to do to detect contour lines though.
As for your remark about backface culling, this is performed using the triangle winding and it depends on your vertex / geom / tess shaders output (https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Face_Culling). So it indirectly depends on the point of view.